# Заморозка очереди до выполнения запроса

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, axios

Работаю с vuejs. Но, как я понимаю, вопрос относится и к js.

На загружаемой странице размещено несколько компонентов, связанных между собой данными через общее хранилище данных. В самом начале в компоненте `Start` из БД загружаются через [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) данные-справочники, необходимые для работы. Сам axios настроен глобально

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    // console.log('Отправлен запрос...');
    return config;
}, (error) => axios_error(error));

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    // console.log('Получен ответ.');
    return response.data;
}, (error) => axios_error(error));

function axios_error(error) {
    console.log('Ошибка запроса axios');
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

Так вот, в компоненте `Start` получаю данные из БД. Метод `getLibrary()` запускается автоматически после создания компонента и на локальном сервере занимает примерно 700мс на всё про всё.

```
async getLibrary() {
    let response = await axios.get('/library');
    await this.setLibrary(response);
}
```

Но на странице есть ещё один компонент `Samples`, которые также при создании компонента загружает методом `getSamples()` список образцов из БД и выводит в виде таблицы, используя при этом справочные данные, которые к этому моменту ещё не получены, т.к. первый запрос длится дольше второго - 700мс против 400мс. Эти данные для отображения в виде таблицы загружаются автоматически от того, что сама по себе страница подразумевает их отображение, поэтому делать кнопку, на которую юзеру нужно нажать, чтобы загрузить данные не вариант.

```
async getSamples() {
    let response = await axios.get('/samples');
    await this.setSamples(response);
},
```

Вот и получается накладка (возникает ошибка - невозможно получить данные для отображения, которых нет) - данные справочных ещё нет, а они уже нужны. И вроде бы используется `async-await`, но делу не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть? Мне нужно, чтобы все остальные запросы отправлялись только после того, как справочные данные из `library` будут получены.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Не показывать текущие данные, если базовые данные ещё не загружены

В примере базовые данные хранятся в vuex store (вроде и в вопросе так).

```
<template>
  <div v-if="baseData && currentData">
    {{ baseData }}
    {{ currentData }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      currentData: null,
    }),
    async mounted() {
      this.currentData = await getSamples();
    },
    computed: mapGetters(['baseData']),
  }
</script>
```

Если перед отображением базовые и текущие данные комбинируются в `computed`-свойстве, то нужно будет в этом свойстве возвращать `null` если базовые данные равны `null`, а в шаблоне проверять на `null` это свойство.

### 2. Ждать завершения запроса базовых данных

Если базовые данные запрашиваются один раз (и являются глобальными для приложения), то можно сохранить `Promise` их получения в глобальную переменную, а в нужном месте вызвать `await` от этой переменной (можно сколько угодно раз вызывать `await` от `Promise`, каждый раз будет возвращаться корректный результат):

```
// в любом файле
export const baseDataPromise = axios.get('/library');

// там где нужны базовые данные
async getSamples() {
    const response = await axios.get('/samples');
    await baseDataPromise;
    await this.setSamples(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо дать сигнал из компонента `Start` компоненту `Samples` что метод `getLibrary` получил данные, ничего сложного на самом деле.

Можете просто в свойство `data` компонента `Start` добавить свойство: `libraryLoaded: null` и немного изменить функцию:

```
async getLibrary() {
    let response = await axios.get('/library');
    await this.setLibrary(response);
    this.libraryLoaded = true; // данные загружены
}
```

Далее `libraryLoaded` надо передать для `Samples` через props(не видно какая у вас разметка, но надеюсь суть понятна):

```
<samples :libraryLoaded="libraryLoaded"></samples>
```

И в самом `Samples` добавьте `libraryLoaded`(надеюсь вы знаете как, не хочу делать ответ очень большим и быть дальше от сути)

Последний шаг: в `Samples` нужно отследить изменение `libraryLoaded` и запустить `getSamples`, добавьте в компонент свойство watch:

```
watch: {
    libraryLoaded () {
        // getLibrary выполнилось и сделало свою задачу, тут код сработает после выполнения getLibrary
        this.getSamples(); // выполняет метод компонента
    }
}
```

Надеюсь помог.